# singleton for initializing instance

Tags: c++, singleton, instance

I am reading , and I have question in the example below.

SINGLEON

```
Class MazeFactory{
public:
   static MazeFactory* Instance();
protected:
   MazeFactory();
private:
   static MazeFactory* _instance;
};

MazeFactory* MazeFactory::_instance = 0;
MazeFactory* MazeFactory::Instance(){
   if(_instance == 0){
      _instance = new MazeFactory;
   }
   return _instance;
}
```

For ''MazeFactory* MazeFactory::_instance = 0;', where should I need to put this? In the definition of this class? Is there another choice to initialize it? When I read it, I just know the design is like this, but I didn't get the point why design like this.

Answer (score 0):

As per definition of singleton, you just need to create the instance only when first you access it. So to make sure you enter into the if condition only once you have to initialize it to NULL. Normally the initialization is done in the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

static private can be initialized outside the class  but only once .  many  posts on singleton would show you this as well . And yes this does not break access rules .